# How to access CLI from installed Pip/Python venv script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, command-line-interface, python-venv

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but I'm hoping someone can clarify something that may be quite simple.

What I want is to use the tool `eyeD3` which is [a CLI](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html). The confusing bit is that on the [install page](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) it says it should be installed with Pip. Thus, I created a virtual environment and installed the package there.

Okay great, but how do I actually use it now? Because every instruction says to use it as a command line tool. But if it's installed as a pip package then the "eyed3" command is not magically going to be placed in my PATH to be used as intended. So what am I not getting here?

Alternatively I may just download it using `sudo dnf install python-eyed3` which should work.

But I really want to educate myself if I'm understanding something wrong, so I can better understand and utilize pip and virtual environments with Python.

Comment: `pip` can also install command line tools into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: See this: https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html

If you're in your venv, you should be able to run the help command.

Comment: "*But if it's installed as a pip package then the "eyed3" command is not magically going to be placed in my PATH…*" Well, `pip` doesn't necessary install scripts into a directory in your `$PATH`, it depends on the version of `pip` and the very `$PATH`. But when `pip` installs scripts into a directory not in `$PATH` it prints a warning saying where it installed the scripts. In a virtual environment scripts are always installed into its `bin` (or `Scripts`) folder.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback everyone. I will keep all of this in mind and definitely reference this next time I'm installing something via Pip.